# Python requests post blocked by server

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to login a site with my username and password, go to the report page, select the criteria and download the report. I'm trying to use requests to do it automatically.

So far I have:

```
report_page_url = 'http://url......'
signin = {username, password}
data = {
     'from_day': '1',
     'from_month': '3',
     'from_year': '2016'}

 with requests.Session() as s:
     s.post(login_url, data=signin)
     download = s.post(report_page_url, data=data)
```

I can login the site with the first post, and download the page content of report page.

However, every time I do requests.post on the report page and pass in the params to fill the form, it redirect me to a page with error messages:

> *You are attempting to modify settings from a URL that does not appear to have come from a FreePBX page link or button. This can occur if you
>   manually typed in the URL below. This action has been blocked because
>   the HTTP_REFERER does not match your current SERVER. If you require
>   this access, you can set Check Server Referrer=false in Advanced
>   Settings to disable this security check.*

Is there anyway to go around it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Are you asking us to help you bypass security on someone else's site?

Comment: Is this your FreePbx server?

Comment: @IanAuld um ... this is not my site/server but we pay for the service. I just want to download report automatically. Unfortunately they don't have any apis. I've done this with other sites to download report, saved a lot of time and never run into this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like they're actually inspecting the `HTTP_REFERER` and denying posts from foreign places. Try adding a `http_referer` header to the request, something like:

```
s.headers.update({'referer': my_referer})
```

You'll need to work out what value they're expecting to see in `my_referer`.  Probably just their own domain name.

Comment: Thank you so much! Pass in its domain, works perfect.